# PS3 games have sound but no video

Tags: ps3, hdmi

It's probably been nearly a year since I played a game on my PS3 but today I decided wanted to play some. My PS3 is connected through HDMI. When I open the game I get no video but there is sound. I use the PS3 a lot (earlier today actually) for streaming Netflix and Hulu and there's no issues - video and sound work great. I tried several games (both discs and games on the HD) and got the same result - sound but no video. I swapped HDMI cables, changed HDMI ports on the TV, and held the power button for a few seconds during turn-on to reset the video settings but still no luck. I'm at a bit of a loss. If anyone has any other ideas I'd definitely appreciate hearing them!

Comment: Let me just get this straight; you have no video at all? Or does the main OS screen on the PS3 have video and sound, but as soon as you launch a game you don't get video?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I do have video for everything except games. I can  watch Netflix and Hulu, I can go around the PS3 menus fine, but as soon as I launch a game I lose video (but keep sound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, when I swapped out the TV everything worked fine. I'm going to assume my TV is being cranky since I don't have a better explanation.